# WYSIWYG Spreadsheet/Tables

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, table

I am searching for a JS library to edit HTML tables in a WYSIWYG way.

Required features:

- open source
- Adding new columns, rows
- Line breaks in cells should be possible
- alignment of cell content should be possible: left-aligned, centered, right-aligned

Answer (score 1):

I recommend TinyMCE and NicEdit!

Comment: A little more content with this answer would be helpful. Perhaps addressing the specific bullet points and adding links to the recommended programs.

Comment: NicEdit: latest news from 2012: Maintenance release to fix nicUpload
Note: this project is not actively developed anymore, but will continue to operate for existing users.